# Scaled Harnack inequality $\sup_{B_r} v \le c\,(1-r)^{-p}\, \inf_{B_r} v$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, elliptic-pde

Where can I find a proof of the following scaled version of Harnack inequality?

> Let $v$ be a non-negative solution of ${L}u = 0$ in $B_1$, with $L$ a uniformly elliptic operator. Then, for $r<1$, there exist constants $c$ and $p$ such that 
>   $\sup_{B_r} v \le c\,(1-r)^{-p}\, \inf_{B_r} v.$

Comment: It follows from applying the usual Harnack inequality to a sequence of balls. For example, applying Harnack in $B_1$ gives $u|_{B_{1/2}} \leq Cu(0)$. Applying it in balls of radius $1/2$ centered at points on $\partial B_{1/2}$ gives $u|_{B_{3/4}} \leq C^2u(0)$. Continuing we get $u|_{B_{1-2^{-k}}} \leq C^ku(0)$, giving polynomial growth near the boundary with power $p \sim \log C / \log 2$.

Comment: @ConnorMooney How does the last inequality in your remark give that polynomial growth $(1-r)^{-p}$? Could you add more details on this in an answer, please?

Comment: Sure, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual Harnack inequality says that $C^{-1}u(x) \leq \inf_{B_{\rho/2}(x)}u \leq \sup_{B_{\rho/2}(x)} u \leq Cu(x)$ for any $B_{\rho}(x) \subset B_1$ and $C$ universal depending on the ellipticity constants, etc. of $L$. Applying this with $x = 0$ and $\rho = 1$ gives
$$C^{-1}u(0) \leq \inf_{B_{1-2^{-1}}}u \leq \sup_{B_{1-2^{-1}}} u \leq Cu(0).$$
Applying it again for all $x \in \partial B_{1/2}$ and $\rho = 1/2$, and using the previous inequality, gives
$$C^{-2}u(0) \leq \inf_{B_{1-2^{-2}}}u \leq \sup_{B_{1-2^{-2}}}u \leq C^2u(0).$$
Proceeding inductively with $x \in \partial B_{1-2^{-k}}$ and $\rho = 2^{-k}$ gives 
$$C^{-k}u(0) \leq \inf_{B_{1-2^{-k}}}u \leq \sup_{B_{1-2^{-k}}}u \leq C^ku(0),$$
so in particular
$$\sup_{B_{1-2^{-k}}}u \leq C^{2k} \inf_{B_{1-2^{-k}}}u.$$
For $r \in (0,\,1)$ choose $k \geq 1$ such that $1-2^{1-k} \leq r \leq 1-2^{-k}$, and let $p = 2\frac{\log C}{\log 2}$. Since $B_r \subset B_{1-2^{-k}}$ the previous inequality gives
$$\sup_{B_r} u \leq C^{2k} \inf_{B_r}u = 2^p(2^{1-k})^{-p} \inf_{B_r}u.$$
Since $1-r \leq 2^{1-k}$ the right side is bounded above by $2^p(1-r)^{-p}\inf_{B_r}u$, completing the proof.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also have a related question which is related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339551/a-consequence-of-de-giorgi-oscillation-lemma